# Adding data frame below another data frame

Tags: r

I want to do the following:

I have a Actual Sales Dataframe

```
Dates       Actual
24/04/2017  58
25/04/2017  59
26/04/2017  58
27/04/2017  154
28/04/2017  117
29/04/2017  127
30/04/2017  178
```

Another data frame of Predicted values

```
Dates           Predicted
01/05/2017      68.54159
02/05/2017      90.7313
03/05/2017      82.76875
04/05/2017      117.48913
05/05/2017      110.3809
06/05/2017      156.53363
07/05/2017      198.14819
```

Add the predicted Sales data frame below the Actual data Frame in following manner:

```
Dates      Actual   Predicted
24/04/2017  58  
25/04/2017  59  
26/04/2017  58  
27/04/2017  154 
28/04/2017  117 
29/04/2017  127 
30/04/2017  178 
01/05/2017        68.54159
02/05/2017        90.7313
03/05/2017        82.76875
04/05/2017        117.48913
05/05/2017        110.3809
06/05/2017        156.53363
07/05/2017        198.14819
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(d1, d2)
```

you get:

```
        Dates Actual Predicted
1  24/04/2017     58        NA
2  25/04/2017     59        NA
3  26/04/2017     58        NA
4  27/04/2017    154        NA
5  28/04/2017    117        NA
6  29/04/2017    127        NA
7  30/04/2017    178        NA
8  01/05/2017     NA  68.54159
9  02/05/2017     NA  90.73130
10 03/05/2017     NA  82.76875
11 04/05/2017     NA 117.48913
12 05/05/2017     NA 110.38090
13 06/05/2017     NA 156.53363
14 07/05/2017     NA 198.14819
```

Or with:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(d1,d2), fill = TRUE)
```

Or with:

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(d1,d2)
```

Comment: You forgot to include the way of solving it with basic R: `merge(d1,d2,all = T)`